# cannot convert mysql query to linq statement

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, linq-to-sql, sql-to-linq-conversion

My SQL query that works as expected:

```
SELECT SUM(outcome), toaddress
FROM lot l
JOIN incomingpayment ip
ON l.incomingpayment_id = ip.id
WHERE outcome > 0
GROUP BY ip.toaddress
ORDER BY SUM(outcome) DESC
```

I am trying to turn this into a LINQ statement, without great success anyway:

```
var result = 

from l in session.Query<Lot>().ToList()
join ip in session.Query<IncomingPayment>().ToList()
on l.IncomingPayment equals ip
where l.Outcome > 0
group ip by new {ip.ToAddress}
into g
select new
{
   Address = g.Key,
   SumAmount = g.Sum(x => x.Outcome)
};
```

`Outcome` in the last line is a `Lot`'s field and since I'm grouping `IncomingPayment` (`group ip...`) it's not available at the `g.Sum()` call.

What am I missing here?

Comment: what is the type of Outcome??

Comment: What ORM are you using? Why don't you create the proper mappings and avoid joins altogether? Even better, create a view and map to it. LINQ isn't a replacement for SQL, trying to recreate the same query typically results in pain

Comment: @EhsanSajjad `outcome` is a `decimal`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am using NHibernate over MySQL. The domain is pretty complex and I cannot change the mappings at this point, I would have to change hundreds of lines of code. I am not sure how to create a view but thanks for the tip, I will check it out if no solution is found.

Comment: Creating a new mapping is only a few lines - in this case you only have to add a relation between the two entities, so you can write `myLot.Payments`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos oh so you suggest I should create additional mappings, not alter the existing ones?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I created a new mapping and it seems to work, thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
var result = from g in (from l in session.Query<Lot>().ToList()
             join ip in session.Query<IncomingPayment>().ToList()
             on l.IncomingPayment equals ip.Id
             where l.Outcome > 0
             select new { Address = ip.ToToAddress, Outcome = l.Outcome})
             group g by g.Address
             select new
             {
                 Address = g.Key,
                 SumAmount = g.Sum(x => x.Outcome)
             };
```

Or more consisely:

```
Lots = session.Query<Lot>().ToList();
IncomingPayments = session.Query<IncomingPayment>().ToList();

var result = Lots.Join(IncomingPayments, 
                       x=>x.IncomingPayment,  
                       y=>y.Id,
                       (x,y) => new
                       {
                           Address = x.ToToAddress,
                           OutCome = y.Outcome
                       }).GroupBy(x => x.Address, 
                                  x => x.Outcome,
                                  (kew, group) =>
                                  {
                                      Address = key,
                                      SumAmount = group.Sum()
                                  });
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. It returns "ambiguous invocation" for `g.Sum()`, and `x.Outcome` is still unavailable.

Comment: @DougPeters please give me few minutes to correct it. Thanks for being patient

Comment: @DougPeters please try my updated version and let me know. Thanks !

Comment: neither scripts seems to work but I'm giving you an upvote for your efforts anyway.

Comment: @DougPeters thank you for the upvote, but our problem is why they don't work. Did you get an error message?  An error message could help us to find out what went wrong...

Comment: Well I can't tell what is the exact problem, these could help: http://s29.postimg.org/km55eefyv/482.jpg and http://s27.postimg.org/4wm8wig8z/483.jpg

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56354/discussion-between-christos-and-doug-peters).